# Rails store numbers with 2 decimal places after comma in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I am doing PDFs for invoices in my system and I would like to be able to store numbers with two decimal places in the database. I am using `MoneyRails` gem for dealing with currencies, I have setup `precision: 10` and `scale: 2` on the database level (I use `postgres` as my DB) but I am getting only 1 decimal place after comma. Why?

```
class AddPrecisionToInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_column :invoices, :total_net_amount_cents, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 2, default: 0.00
    change_column :invoices, :total_gross_amount_cents, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 2, default: 0.00
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :invoices, :total_net_amount_cents, :bigint
    change_column :invoices, :total_gross_amount_cents, :bigint
  end
end
```

invoice.rb

```
monetize :total_net_amount_cents
monetize :total_gross_amount_cents
```

In rails console,

```
invoice.total_gross_amount_cents = Money.new(20_000_00)
invoice.total_gross_amount.to_f #=> 2000.0
```

Is it possible to store numbers with two decimal places in DB, like `20,000.00`?
I don't want to display the PDF in a view so I want to be able to drop the number into my DB as I got it from params from my front-end application without further formatting it in a view.

Comment: You are not storing numbers with two decimal places. The `.` is a decimal, the `,` is a thousand separator. If you're looking to store the value as submitted completely unaltered then you need to store it as a string. The value of that data is then more limited, e.i. can't be summed etc.

Comment: I checked the value in `psql` console and it's saved as 1200.00, with two decimal places so it's correct. I just needed a way to format the value properly after retrieving it from DB as `money-rails` converts the value to a Money object. I can call `value.format` to a get a value suitable for dispalying it but not suitable for calculations. I need to figure this out still.

Comment: My apologies @jedi, I read your question two fast. I assumed you wanted all the formatting stored (e.g. the comma and the period).

Comment: No probs. I just want to keep the decimals with two digits. Stil lhaven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following, (using in model)

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::number_to_delimited('%.2f' % '3423432.43234', delimiter: ",", separator: ".")

# => "3,423,432.43"
```

Here, in above input `3423432.43234` is provided as string, you can provide it as number also.

You can directly use `number_with_delimiter` in view

Comment: Sorry, I have not been very precise in my question and I have updated it now. I don't want to use it in a view becuase I just create a PDF and then upload it to Amazon so no further formatting in a view, etc. Does it make sense?

Comment: formatted number with commas can be stored in table only as a string but if you retrieve them back for calculation you have to convert them by removing commas for operation.

Comment: I suggest you to store these values in table as float. But whenever you want to display in web view or PDF template, process it as I said.

Comment: `"200,00".to_f #=> 200.0`, `"200.00".to_f #=> 200.0` so storing the value as a string for further processig won't help, I guess.

Comment: @jedi why do you think `to_f` is intelligent one, try `'2334,343,44'.gsub(',','')`

Comment: OK so `'2334,343,44'.gsub(',','').to_f #=> 233434344.0`

Comment: No need of `to_f` here as if you store `int` data in `float` datatype column of table, it will get automatically converted in float

Comment: Yes, but it will not give me `200.00` but `200.0`

Comment: It make no sense. Let it be in that format. When you want to display, you can have number of zeros to display as per my code provided. by logic, 200.0 == 200.00000, so do not worry

Answer (score 0):

The money-rails gem requires `monetize` columns to be numeric in the database.  However, it comes with [some helper methods](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#helpers) that you could use to re-format as you wish in your model:

```
# inside Invoice model
require "money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension"
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  include MoneyRails::ActionViewExtension
  # ...
  def total_gross_amount_formatted
    humanized_money total_gross_amount
  end
end
```

Then in your PDF you can just reference the new formatted attribute:

```
@invoice_instance.total_gross_amount_formatted
```